# What do these errors mean and how do I fix them: Kivy and Tensorflow Python Image Recognition Algorithym

Tags: python, android, ios, kivy, command-prompt

I hope you're having a great day!
I have been trying to get my first machine learning algorithm working via python/kivy/tensorflow

I am following a guide on how to accomplish this.
Link: https://steemit.com/utopian-io/@faad/tensorflow-image-recognition-app-in-kivy

And the github:
https://github.com/faad1/tensorflow-image-recognition

I'm doing the one called mian.py

I don't know if I am missing dependencies.
But the camera doesn't have a valuable provider :(

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label


Builder.load_string('''
<CaputeImage>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Camera:
        id: camera
        resolution: (720, 480)
        play: True

    Button:
        text: "Capture"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
''')

class CaputeImage(BoxLayout):
  pass

class ImageRecognition(App):

    def build(self):
        return CaputeImage()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    imagerecognition = ImageRecognition()
    imagerecognition.run()
```

Apparently, It's supposed to display a camera but it gives me these errors:

```
No Module named picamera, gi, and cv2

setattr(widget_set, key, value),
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 6:

...
       4:    Camera:
       5:        id: camera

6:        resolution: (720, 480)
       7:        play: True
       8:
```

And a couple more that are to long to show.
Please explain what is going on and why I am getting these errors.
Thank you, have a great day! :)

Comment: The first line of error clearly states lack of modules (picamera, gi, and cv2). Install them with pip, and try again.

Comment: @Ernest Pokropek When I try to install it I get an error that it can't run wheel :(

Comment: make sure that you installed pip and wheel correctly (try `pip instal wheel`, and check your pip version)